# Unable to shutdown an Azure VM - can not get control of it and still getting charged for it

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm running `Stop-AzureVM` command and get the following error.

As I understand it the only way to shutdown a VM and not get charged for it is via this PowerShell command.

How can I Shutdown and Deallocate this VM or otherwise stop being charged for it?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Stop-AzureVM -Name "SQL1" -ServiceName "my-svc-name" -Force -Verbose
VERBOSE: 10:51:17 AM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
VERBOSE: 10:51:17 AM - Begin Operation: Stop-AzureVM
Stop-AzureVM : InternalError : The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Stop-AzureVM -Name "SQL1" -ServiceName "ec-spsvcname2" -Force -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Stop-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.StopAzureVMCommand

VERBOSE: 10:51:52 AM - Completed Operation: Stop-AzureVM
```

I can connect to the VM and shut it down, but its then not deallocated.
I've tried restarting the VM, shutting down the VM through the portal, which doesn't work either, but the PowerShell still gives the same error.

**Update**
This link indicates the status needs be stopped deallocated.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/f608528e-a9f8-45b3-8d23-4211168cc087/stopped-deallocated

This link -http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/ - states
states `If the VM status is "Stopped" you are still being billed. Only status "Stopped (Deallocated)" means that VM is no longer incurring charges.`

However, it also states you can stop the VM through the portal to stop being charged, this I believe is incorrect - as far as I know you cant get to "stopped (deallocated)" through the portal. Only through PowerShell.

**Update** 
I've updated the question title, as getting charged for it is only part of the problem, I would like to regain control of it.

Comment: if you stop the cloud service that contains the VM, that gets you to "stopped allocated" as well. (assuming you want the shutdown all VMs in the cloud service)

Comment: @JuneT - tried that, and for the cloud service in question that is failing, it didnt stop deallocate, it just set the status to stopped.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to use the portal to put a VM into a stopped state where you don't get charged for it. I do this all the time.

Comment: @GregD - Is it possible to put the VM into the stopped (deallocated) state through the portal? Or is it in the stopped state and not getting charged?

Comment: I've just shut down another VM through the portal interface and it went to "Stopped (Deallocated)" state. So the problem remains with two VMs that I have in a "Stopped" state, and I cant restart them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Microsoft support that confirmed to avoid billing the status must be `Stopped (Deallocated)`. (although the answer from Trevor Sullivan indicates he has seen different behaviour)

I also stopped a different VM through the portal and the status did go to `Stopped (Deallocated)`

I also stopped a different cloud service and all the VM's in that cloud service went to `Stopped (Deallocated)`

Once the troublesome VM's got into some sort of failed state, stopping/starting through the portal directly or via powershell either didnt work or didnt put it into `Stopped (Deallocated)` status.

However it appears time heals things in Azure, I have tried to stop/start a couple of times per day over the last few days without success, but now around 72 hours later it has started working again.

Answer (score 1):

If a VM is in "Stopped (Deallocated)" you can see it in this state from the portal by looking at the virtual machine's status on the Dashboard. It will state "Stopped (Deallocated)". You can place a machine into "Stopped (Deallocated)" by shutting the VM down via the portal. Note that the portal will warn about losing the IP Addresses.

If your virtual machine is currently "Stopped" instead of "Stopped (Deallocated)" and you're being billed for it, starting it and then immediately shutting it down via the portal ought to put it in "Stopped (Deallocated)" so that you won't get billed for it.

Do you have anything special going on with your machine or subscription? If it's a vanilla "Stopped" virtual machine and you cannot start it to shut it down, contact Windows Azure Support for help. If your virtual machine is running and refuses to go into "Stopped (Deallocated)" when you shut it down, contact support for help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately there is no technical support for a standard subscription. You need to pay for it. The page suggests ask a question on stackoverflow or the relevant msdn forum.

Answer (score 0):

You are only billed for virtual machines in the running state. See FAQ here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/

Shut it down through the UI for now.

Comment: From my understanding this answer is incorrect - I've updated the question with a link.

Comment: From your link it states "If the VM status is "Stopped" you are still being billed. Only status "Stopped (Deallocated)" means that VM is no longer incurring charges." - It also states you can stop the VM through the portal to stop being charged, this bit is incorrect - as far as I know you cant get to stopped (deallocated) through the portal. Only through PowerShell

Comment: What I'm reading is this: *"A Virtual Machine is billed based on the duration of time your VM was deployed for. If your VM was deployed for less than an hour, or multiple hours plus some fraction of hour, you will be charged for that duration only. Windows Azure does not round up the partial hour to full hour for billing - you pay for exactly that duration of time that your VM was in 'running' state."*

Comment: Incidentally, I shutdown a VM earlier today, that I had left running for the last few weeks. When I look at today's billing report, I can see that I've only been billed for about half the day, instead of the full day. The status of mine does *not* say "deallocated." I think that the documentation is out-of-date.

Besides, the documentation also does state that if you shutdown the VM using the Windows Azure Portal, you will not be billed. It says that if you shutdown the VM using the Shutdown command inside of the remote VM, then you will still get billed.

Answer (score 0):

If your VMs are deployed as CloudService(using  cspkg) then you cannot deallocate them, you will always be charged as long as CloudService exists no matter what state it is in. If this is the case you won't be able to see them on the *Virtual Machines* tab.

I'm not sure if this is a scenario applies to you though.